# Flutter: conditional bottom navigation bar, to show pages based on if condition

Tags: flutter, conditional-statements, flutter-layout

I have implemented a bottom navigation bar with the logic listed below, and I want to check if the user is logged in. If user is logged in on third tab I want to show the profile page instead of SignIn page. This is my code where I am displaying the bottom navigation bar, I am stuck on what to do after checkIsLoggedIn() async function.

[image: strong text]

After that Im building list of widgets to show the pages in 3 tabs. 
code of which is below,

[image]

so in place of SignIn(), I need to show, if the user is logged in it shows signin other wise, it shows Profile page. 
Please do help me out here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may help.

```
Future<void> checkIfLoggedIn() async {
  SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var id = localStorage.getString('id');
  if (id != null) {
    setState(() {
      _children[2] = ProfilePage();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `checkIfLoggedIn()`, along with `_isLoggedIn` write the following code: 
`_children[2] = Profile()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the last `BottomNavigationItem` as below

```
BottomNavigationItem(
    icon:_isLoggedIn ? Icons.person : Icons.key,
    title:Text(_isLoggedIn ? 'Account' : 'Log in' )
)
```

and you can handle the click event and set the proper page in the `build()` by the same ternary operators using the `_isLoggedIn` variable

```
build(){
    return Scaffold(
        body:_isLoggedIn?ProfilePage():LoginPage()
    );
}
```

Comment: but for the body: I am using a list of widgets  _children[_currentIndex], its not just one page.

Comment: I don't know the whole code..am giving the reference... You can implement in your style...